# c++ malloc and free object creation and deletion

Tags: c++, malloc, free

I will first post my test program in C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
     int x;
     public:
     X()
     {
       cout<<"constructing\n";
       x=0;
     }
     int& getx()
     {
       return x;
     }
     ~X()
     {
       cout<<"destroying\n";
     }
};
int main()
{
     X* p=(X*)malloc(sizeof(X));
     ++p->getx();
     p->getx()*=5;
     cout<<p->getx();
     free(p);
     return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
5
```

Now before anyone complains why i used `malloc` & `free` in a C++ program, I would like to reiterate that it is just a test program and the above could have been done even with `operator new` & `operator delete`. But my questions still remain the same that are:

1. Even though no object of X is created using `malloc or operator new` how can we access the class X's variable x ?
2. Clearly `free & operator delete` also do not destroy the objects and perform mere dallocations. What would happen if I create an object with `new` but use `operator delete or free` instead of `delete` ? Would my object still be there & will it be still usable ?

Comment: Why are you using malloc in c++? Test program is no excuse

Comment: just to ask the above question @EdHeal

Comment: I dont think asking a question should be a problem

Comment: So no practical benefit to anybody

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, since although you've allocated space for an object the same size as `X`, its constructor hasn't been run and so it's not a valid `X`.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: If no constructor is called then the member(s) aren't initialized. Are you asking if reading an uninitialized variable gives meaningful results?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking about. Aren't you already accessing `x` via `getx()`? Do you know it is a mere coincidence that initial `x` value is 0 if you use `malloc`? The object is not initialized...

Comment: use `new` in C++ as it call the objects constructor.  `malloc` does not do that.

Comment: "no object of X is created using `malloc` or `operator new`" If you change your allocation `X* p = new X;`, I think you'll find that an object of X is very much created with `operator new`. Similarly if you replace `free(p);` with `delete p;`

Comment: My question is HOW, I know very well that i ought to use new & delete. but i want to know why the above happens

Comment: You want to know why you can have undefined behavior?

Comment: No @NathanOliver i want to know how did 'p' access 'x' of the Class X eventhough an object of X was never created ?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: Its undefined behavior.  Just because your program has undefined behavior doesn't mean it can't compile and run.  It's just that the behavior/results/outputs could be anything.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya Asking for UB is pretty useless. A minimal change could lead to a totally different behavior, not to talk about using a different Compiler. It's simply not predictable what happens, and why exactly.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya - Undefined behavior means that **absolutely anything** can happen, including you getting the output you expected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because predicting behavior of undefined behavior is not possible.

Comment: _"I would like to reiterate that it is just a test program"_ Irrelevant. Your program has UB. It is folly to analyse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading so many points from so many I myself wrote a program to explain your problem. See below :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class X
{
    int x;
    vector<int> v;
    public:
    X()
    {
      cout<<"constructing\n";
      x=0;
      v.push_back(1);
      v.push_back(2);
    }
    int& getx()
    {
      return x;
    }
    vector<int>& getv()
    {
      return v;
    }
    ~X()
    {
      cout<<"destroying\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    X* p=(X*)operator new(sizeof(X));
    ++p->getx();
    p->getx()*=5;
    cout<<p->getx()<<"\n";
    for (int x:p->getv())
    cout<<x<<" ";
    cout<<"\nexecuted\n";
    operator delete(p);
    return 0;
}
/* Output :-
   5

   executed
*/
```

See how `p` ignored the vector `v` and went for the line `executed`. This is because `vector<int>` being a `class` (or more precisely a `class template`) was never created by `operator new (or malloc in your case)`. Your program showed the output for `x` because it is a primitive type & not a class. For a class you need a constructor & hence `operator new or malloc` aren't suitable for classes & hence the output. If you simply replace `operator new with new` & `operator delete with delete` then the output will be :-

```
constructing
5
1 2 
executed
destroying
```

Now your code gives the correct & apt results ! Congo !

For your second question, NEVER MIX UP `malloc & free` with `new & delete` as it creates UB with not so happening results.

Comment: thnk u for this answer

Answer (score 13):

1. If you deallocate an object created with `new` by calling `free()`, you are deep into undefined behavior. Likewise, if you deallocate a `malloc()`'ed object with `delete`, you have undefined behavior. Whatever you do, never mix the two.
2. `malloc()` has different semantics than `new`: `malloc()` just allocates the memory, it does not call a constructor. `new` does the allocation, and also calls the appropriate constructor.

   Likewise, there is the analogue difference between `free()` and `delete`: `delete` calls the destructor before freeing the memory, `free()` does not.

You can use `malloc()` in C++ to back a true C++ object, but you will have to do the constructor/destructor calls yourself:

```
//The placement-new below needs this:
#include <new>

//This is what new does:
char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));    //allocation only
Foo* foo = new(temp) Foo();    //placement-new: construction only

//This is what delete does:
foo->~Foo();    //destruction only
free((void*)foo);    //deallocation only
```

Note that the placement-new syntax in the second line is the only way to explicitly call a constructor in C++. The destructor can be called explicitly just like any other member. The reason for this asymmetry is that the object really is a valid object before destruction, which is not the case before construction.

---

To your question about why `p->getx()` compiles. That comes down to this little cast in your code:

```
X* p=(X*)malloc(sizeof(X));
      ^
      |
this little cast
```

Here you, the programmer, are explicitly telling the compiler: "I know that the value I'm giving you does not look like a pointer to `X`, but I tell you that it is. So, stupid compiler, just shut up about the type mismatch, and treat it as a pointer to `X` anyway, because I, the human, your god, told you so!"

So what can your compiler do? It shuts up about the type mismatch, and treats the pointer as a pointer to `X`, as you told it. If that's wrong, that's your problem. Maybe the program will run fine anyway, maybe it crashes, maybe it silently corrupts data, maybe a pink elephant appears. Your compiler won't care. It's only care is that it did your wish. Compilers can be very obedient.

Comment: If malloc never created object & free never destroyed one then how could C use data structures like linked list, etc just by using these 2 & not result into an UB !!!!!!!!!1

Comment: Thats probably one of the reasons @AnkitAcharya why you should forget C & concentrate on C++

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: C doesn't have objects.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya: Very simple; C doesn't have classes and therefore doesn't have constructors (or member functions). When using `struct` types in C, all `p->x` (for example) does is access the appropriate memory location.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya You are confusing the meaning of "create". Creating an object in C++ means: allocating the space for the variables (`malloc` can do that), and calling all the object's inherited constructors chain (either `new` or declaring the object on stack can do that) so that the object will be initially at a valid state, ***on the context of its own class***.

Comment: @Anwesha That would be a bit rash. Not everything that C does is evil, and not everything that C++ does is good. And there are things which C does better than C++ (variable length multidimensional arrays and compound literals). True, I generally prefer C++ myself as well, but it's not a pure win over C.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this part of the question: "What would happen if I create an object with new but use operator delete or free instead of delete ? Would my object still be there & will it be still usable ?"

Allocating with `malloc` and freeing with `delete` is undefined behavior. There is no guarantee that the implementation will use C's `free` after calling the object's destructor.

Likewise the opposite. If you allocate with `new`, there is no guarantee that the returned pointer came from an internally called `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`, only cases that it would be safe to pass the pointer to `free`.

Even if it works, it may break the program and/or leak resources, because you would either skip object's constructor or destructor.

EDIT:

You said "Clearly free & operator delete also do not destroy the objects and perform mere dallocations." Well, that is wrong. `delete` will call object's destructor, so it will destroy and then deallocate.

As for the clarified question in comments, for "why can you still access x", well, `malloc` will allocate the full space occupied by the object (which, in your case, I believe to be just the `x` variable), and the variable will be there, only the constructor will not be called, so, its value will not be set to zero. If it was initially zero when you ran the program, it was merely a coincidence.

Comment: There's no `delete` in the code. This is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Um.. that is not what is going on.  There is no mixing of malloc and delete going on.  The issue is using malloc does not construct X

Comment: how can the variable be there even when the constructor is not called !!!!!!!
that seems outrageous !!!!!!
plus i think now how could C use data structure programs like linked list & trees using just malloc & free & not result into an UB !!!!!!!!!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I know there is no mixing of `delete` and `malloc` in that code, but in the question 2., op clearly asks about it.

Comment: Technically it's UB. The compiled code will likely try to access a memory location, whether the object was constructed or not.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya The space for the variables are created during the allocation, in your case `malloc`. The role of the constructor is to give the initial meaningful state for your object, not "make the variable exists" (whatever it means). And I can't pinpoint the specs, but I don't believe it is undefined behavior on the context of the language, it may be just unidealized memory read.

Comment: @AnkitAcharya Many programs run fine for years, even though they exhibit UB: Seemingly correct behavior is a valid implementation of undefined behavior, after all. That's the problem with UB: You may not notice it for a very long time, because everything seems to run fine. But then, someday you change your compiler, and your program goes BOOM. Or someone comes up with a piece of input data to your program that will trick it into starting a root shell for them. Or someday you find out that the results of your program where just slightly, but disastrously off. Scared yet?